# How to launch new Activity from instantiateItem() function implements ViewPagerTabProvider

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I would like to launch new activity under  instantiateItem() Function. What i understand about this function is that it is just allowed to add TextView under this function itself. Is is possible to create new activity or intent below the function ? Codes are described as below.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

    RelativeLayout v = new RelativeLayout(mContext);

    TextView t = new TextView(mContext);
    t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    t.setText(mData[position]);
    t.setTextSize(30);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    v.addView(t);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(v, 0);

    return v;

}
```

Comment: Why you want new Activity to launch in instantiateItem?

In instantiateItem you not only add a Textview, you can also inflate a new Layout in instantiateItem...

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem thanks for reply. I want to launch the new activity since i have different activities let say like listing for each tab.that would be great if you could guide me with some example codes.

Comment: I afraid you can't able to do, what you are planning to do :) What you can do with view pager, I write in my answer. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want diffrent layout for each page then you can do something like this, in `instantiateItem`

```
View parent_view = null;

        if (position == 0) {
            parent_view = getViewForPageOne();

        } else if (position == 1) {
            parent_view = getViewForPageTwo();

        .........

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(parent_view, 0);
        return parent_view;

    }
```

and

```
private View getViewForPageOne(){
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_page_one, null);
         TextView whatText =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);
         whatText.setText("Page One");
         ....
         ....

         return v;
    }
```